# Excel Vba How to avoid iterating folder repeatedly

Tags: excel, vba

i currently have a code that iterates through the folder and the files inside the folder to "get data"(not important) into the excel sheet

but every time i run the code, it will need to go through the whole folder, and lets say if i have 300 files it will then go through all 300 files to "get data" even though the data is already existing in the excel sheet thus that is extremely time consuming.

i would like to scan through Column "E"(contains filenames) on my excel sheet named "Main" and then add it into the dictionary and then after that check for new file name, E.G meaning if first run saved 60 file names into dictionary, if 2nd run has new files, add it into the dictionary then "get data" if no new files then just leave it.

Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thank you so much.

i managed to find this code here that seems to be what i'm supposed to use, but i have no idea how i can tweak it to match my needs,

```
Sub DictionaryGroupData(rngInput As Range, keyColIndex As Long, blHeaders As Boolean)
    'Must add reference to Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range, rng As Range, rngTemp As Range
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim strVal As String
    Dim varOrigItems As Variant, varUniqueItems As Variant, varKey As Variant, _
        varItem As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set rng = rngInput.Columns(keyColIndex)
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    ' set compare mode to text
    dict.CompareMode = TextCompare

    ' offset by one row if range has headers
    If blHeaders Then
        With rngInput
            Set rngInput = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
        End With
    End If

    ' add keys and values to dictionary
    With rngInput
        For Each rngCell In rngInput.Columns(keyColIndex).Cells
            i = i + 1
            strVal = rngCell.Text

            ' add new key and item range
            If Not dict.Exists(strVal) Then
                dict.Add strVal, .Rows(i)

            ' merge item ranges of existing key
            Else
                Set rngTemp = Union(.Rows(i), dict(strVal))
                dict.Remove strVal ' simply updating the item in a loop will cause a run-time error!
                dict.Add strVal, rngTemp
            End If
        Next rngCell
    End With

    For Each varKey In dict.Keys
        ' *********************************************
        'Insert your code here
        ' *********************************************
        Debug.Print varKey & ": " & dict.Item(varKey).Address ' remove in production
    Next varKey
    ' *********************************************
    ' or add code here for specific key actions
    ' dict("A").Select
    ' *********************************************
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Store them in a `Dictionary`, and check if names are in the dictionary with `Exists` method. If you however want to keep these file in a safe place when you close your project and re-open it, then store them either on your worksheet or external txt file or so.

Comment: No matter what you must iterate over all the file names in the directory, can't escape that. However you can store processed file names somewhere (a dictionary, or you can load them from a range) and only process new ones.

Comment: You could just save the date and time somewhere in your workbook of your last run. Then when you run the macro again, just open the files that were added to the folder after your last run

Comment: could any of you possibly provide me a snippet of the code pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some sample code that shows how to use a dictionary for your stated purpose:

```
Sub tgr()

    'Define the column containing your Filenames here
    Const FileNamesColumn As String = "E"

    'Enter the folder path that contains the files you'll be looping through here
    Dim FolderPath As String
    FolderPath = "C:\Test\"

    'Set the worksheet to where your data is stored, this sample code assumes activesheet of activeworkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    'Prepare the dictionary variable
    Dim FileNamesList As Object
    Set FileNamesList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Loop through the filenames in your filenames column, starting at row 2 to skip the header row (adjust as necessary)
    Dim FileName As Variant
    For Each FileName In ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, FileNamesColumn), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, FileNamesColumn).End(xlUp)).Value
        If Not FileNamesList.Exists(FileName) Then FileNamesList(FileName) = FileName
    Next FileName

    'Ensure that the FolderPath ends in \
    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"

    'Get initial file for iterating over what's stored in the directory
    'The *.xl?? restricts what you're itering over to only Excel files
    Dim CurrentFileName As String
    CurrentFileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl??")

    'Create a variable to track how many new files were processed
    Dim ProcessedCount As Long
    ProcessedCount = 0

    'Disable calculation, events, and screenupdating to allow code to run faster and prevent "screen flickering"
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Begin the loop
    Do While Len(CurrentFileName) > 0
        'Verify this is a new file and that it's name doesn't exist in the dictionary FileNamesList
        If Not FileNamesList.Exists(CurrentFileName) Then
            'New file found, provide status update to user and increase ProcessedCount
            Application.StatusBar = "Importing from new file: " & CurrentFileName   'Provide status update so user knows code is running
            ProcessedCount = ProcessedCount + 1

            'Open the file and process it
            With Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & CurrentFileName)
                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                'Your code for processing this new file here'
                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                'Example where you bring in the first value of the opened workbook and return it to the first open cell of column A of your "master" workbook that you're running the code from
                ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = .Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value

                .Close False    'Close the opened file
            End With

            'Add this new filename to your list in filenames column so that the next time the code is run this file will be skipped (if this isn't already done with your code for processing the file)
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, FileNamesColumn).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = CurrentFileName
        End If
        CurrentFileName = Dir()    'Advance to next file
    Loop

    'Re-enable calculation, events, and screenupdating
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Application.StatusBar = vbNullString    'Clear the status bar so it resumes normal operation

    'Provide message informing the code has completed and how many new files were processed
    MsgBox ProcessedCount & " new files processed."

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much! can i please ask one last help from u? this is the last step that needs to be done before my program works! can you please have a look at my editted post?